# WADL2JAVA:Gradle PlugIn

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

So far we were using Maven as build tool, recently we started migrating our projects to use gradle. When we were using maven we used to have

```
cxf-wadl2java-plugin
```

to convert wadl to java code.But with gradle we are having trouble converting wadl to java generated classes.Is there any tool available which we can use in gradle to convert wadl to java pojos or can we still use   `cxf-wadl2java-plugin`?If yes, a working example would help

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily with [wsdl2java gradle plugin](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java).

Something like this:

```
wsdl2java{
    encoding = 'utf-8'
        wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ["-exsh", "true",
             "$projectDir/src/main/your-awesome-service.wsdl"]
    ]
    generatedWsdlDir = file("$buildDir/generated-sources/cxf")
    wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/wsdl")
}
```

Gradle creates a new task named wsdl2java and you can generate the java classes with this.

Comment: mine is wadl not wsdl